# Category of representations of a tensor product algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Given two semisimple unital algebras $A$ and $B$, defined over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, denote their categories of representations by $_A\mathcal{M}$ and $_B\mathcal{M}$ respectively. Can one describe the category of representations of $A \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} B$ as some type of "tensor product" of the categories $_A\mathcal{M}$ and $_B\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: There is a notion of Deligne tensor product of tensor categories, probably that's what you need.

Comment: See also some discussion here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335810/the-tensor-product-of-two-monoidal-categories?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be exactly Deligne's tensor product of abelian categories. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Deligne+tensor+product+of+abelian+categories